# Ikea Tradfri Gateway still not found by app within the same network

Tags: smart-home, ikea-tradfri

I've connected the Tradfri Gateway (GW) to the LAN port of my router. The Internet light (middle) is already stable after some time, but the Network light (topmost) is always pulsing. Anyway, I proceeded to add the GW to the Ikea Home Smart app, but it cannot find the GW. My phone is already connected via wifi from the same router, and the app is allowed to access local network (in its Settings). In the router's web interface, I can see both the Tradfri GW and my phone in the DHCP list. I've already tried resetting to factory defaults first the router, then the GW, but I still face the same issue.

Any suggestion on what else I can do to help the Ikea app detect the GW? Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe your router isolates wired LAN from WiFi

Comment: May I know how to check if this is true?

Comment: that would depend on the router model ... talk to your ISP (internet service provider)

Comment: See if ping works. You can download some app for ping or connect a laptop to the same wifi and try it. Usually, if you're connected to the "guest" network, it will isolate LAN and sometimes also wifi connections from each other. Try pinging the gateway from the PC/phone. Or connect a laptop on WAN and one on wifi and try pinging between them.

Comment: I tried pinging the GW from my laptop which is connected to the same router via wifi. The message displayed was: Destination host unreachable. So it seems the wired LAN and wifi are isolated, correct? I will search for the web's UI on how to undo the setting.

Comment: To be sure, try connecting the laptop to the LAN also and see if the ping works. It may just be that the GW does not support ping (unusual, but possible).